# jQuery.find() ignores root node

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My jQuery object looks like this:

```
var myJq = jQuery("<div class='a'></div><div class='b'></div>")
```

`myJq.find(".a")` returns an empty jQuery object, apparently because `find()` searches only the *children* of the nodes contained in a jQuery object, not the nodes themselves.

How can I grab one of the divs in `myJq` using a selector?

Answer (score 18):

You need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead.

This will filter through items at the top level of the jQuery object.

```
myJq.filter(".a")
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a *.find2()* that'll find both root elements and children:

```
$.fn.find2 = function(selector) {
  return this.filter(selector).add(this.find(selector));
};
```

With this, you can do:

```
var html = '<div class="one"><div class="one"></div></div>';
var el = html.find2(".one"); // will match both divs
```

Here's more about it: http://danielnouri.org/notes/2011/03/14/a-jquery-find-that-also-finds-the-root-element/

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it does not work for cases like `html.find2(".one > .one")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `.filter()`

```
var div = myJq.filter('.a');
```

or (better, faster) use `.first()`

```
var div = myJq.first('.a');
```

**Benchmark**

```
var myJq = jQuery("<div class='a'></div><div class='b'></div>")
var loop = 20000; 

console.time('filter');  
while(loop--){
    var blah = myJq.filter(".a");
}
console.timeEnd('filter');

loop = 20000;

console.time('first');  
while(loop--){
    var blah = myJq.first(".a");
}
console.timeEnd('first');
```

`.first()` is about 8x faster for me.

Comment: True. Grabbing by index would be faster than by selector, but more fragile/higher maintenance if the structure changes. +1

Comment: `.first()` doesn't work like you think.  Try doing `myJq.first('.b')` to see what I mean. `.first()` is simply sugar method for `.eq(0)`

Comment: In other words, the argument you pass is ignored.