# Find elements by class beginning with parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

With a setup like;

```
var o = $('
    <div class="a a-1">
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="c">         
            <div class="a a-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="a a-3"></div>
    </div>
');
```

How do I find all class "`a`" elements?

When I try `o.find('.a')`, elements .a-2 and .a-3 are returned without the parent class (.a-1). So I also tried adding a wrapper `'<div><div class="a a-1">...</div></div>'` but since am using ajax, it messes up front-end rendering.

Any ideas?

*Addendum:*
Someone suggested similarity to [jQuery.find() ignores root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637298/jquery-find-ignores-root-node). No problem except the question requires capturing one element. In that case, `.filter()` should suffice. The question asks "How can I grab one..." In this case I need all of them.

Comment: `.find()` searches in the descendant nodes and does not include the current node from where the query is issued

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: add this in your code `o.find('.a').andSelf('.a')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.find() ignores root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637298/jquery-find-ignores-root-node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For jQuery 1.8 and up, you can use [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

```
o.find(".a").addBack(".a")
```

Prior to jQuery 1.8, use `.andSelf()` (now deprecated) :

```
o.find(".a").andSelf(".a")
```

Comment: will include the self object even if  it doesn't have  your class. in andself specify the class

Answer (score 1):

use [.andSelf()](https://api.jquery.com/andself/) **<< jq 1.8** or [.addBack()](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/) **>>for jq 1.8** it includes also the current targeted node :

```js
var o = $('<div class="a a-1"> <div class="b"></div><div class="c"><div class="a a-2"></div></div> <div class="a a-3"></div></div>');

console.log("number of element with andSelf .a :"+ o.find(".a").andSelf().length);
console.log("number of element with addBack .a :"+ o.find(".a").addBack().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just tried your code, .andSelf() doesn't work in jQuery v3.2

Comment: Yep sorry , in the documentation they mentiened it was deprectaed in 3.0 so , i 've updated the answer to swet both versions :) thnx

Comment: Correct. Now I upvote your answer and comment. Thank you.

Comment: thnks :) , up too :)

Answer (score 1):

find looks inside the set of elements, so you could do:

```
var o = $('
<div class="a a-1">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c">         
        <div class="a a-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a a-3"></div>
</div>
');
```

Then:

```
o = o.appendTo($('<div></div>'));
```

and then:

```
o.find('.a')...
```

Comment: This works. But since am intercepting ajax, this messes up output big league coz different kinds of outputs are passing thru.

Comment: If you use the same variable to render the DOM and do your query, it will... I thought that was the reason why you use `var o = ...` but if you want to use it, you could append to the DOM element where you are rendering the Ajax data, like this `$(element).append(o.html());`, that way the container div that we added won't be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5332377/6199906 (copied it here..)

---

> Here's a *.find2()* that'll find both root elements and children:
>
> ```
> $.fn.find2 = function(selector) {
>   return this.filter(selector).add(this.find(selector));
> };
> ```
>
> With this, you can do:
>
> ```
> var html = '<div class="one"><div class="one"></div></div>';
> var el = html.find2(".one"); // will match both divs
> ```
>
> Here's more about it:
>   http://danielnouri.org/notes/2011/03/14/a-jquery-find-that-also-finds-the-root-element/

Comment: Please don't add answers that point to other answers. When you have more rep you can flag posts as duplicates, for now, simply don't answer them

Comment: Liam is right. Also, you are right. Just tried your code `o.filter('.a').add(o.find('.a'))` it works. Downside is it's a little longer than accepted, and presented as a function, in this case, an overkill.