# Using $.get to load elements from another page does not work for root elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
//load nav menu and footer from index.html
$.get('index.html', function(data) {
    $('#menuItems').replaceWith($(data).find("#menuItems"));  //this works
    $('#footer').replaceWith($(data).find("#footer"));  //this does not work
});
```

The code that loads the menu works but the code that loads the footer does not.  The only difference I can see is that the `#footer` is directly under the `body` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <!-- normal head stuff, script references, meta tags, etc. -->
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav>
        <ul id='menuItems'>
          <li>item</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div>some content here</div>
      <footer id='footer'>stuff</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The basic layout above is the same for `index.html` and the files that pull from it.

In the console if I do some tests, it shows that root elements are not "found":

> ```
> 11:54:12.267 $(data).find('#menuItems').length
> 11:54:12.270 1
> 11:54:15.633 $(data).find('#logo-container').length
> 11:54:15.635 1
> 11:54:23.001 $(data).find('#footer').length
> 11:54:23.004 0
> 11:54:37.008 $(data).find('nav').length
> 11:54:37.012 0
> ```

I really can't think of any other differences.  I'll be glad to provide more info if needed.

Comment: `.find()` searches descendants only.

Comment: Descendants of what?   `$.get` returns the entire HTML document.  Wouldn't `body` be a descendant?  If not, wouldn't `#footer` be a descendant of `body`?  What is the root?

Comment: What is `d` here

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I'll edit, but `d = $(data)`

Comment: Can you give your index.html's required code with main structural components only

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "required code" but the original post has the basic layout of all the HTML files, including index.html. I did edit it to include `head` and a content div.  Please clarify what else you need.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the `$(data)` object contain `body` with `footer` within it? It appears so on your edited question, just clarifying

Comment: Try getting tag element : $(data).find('footer').length in console

Comment: Yes, `data` is a string that consists of the entire `index.html` file.  `$(data)` is an object with a length of 39 that includes `29: footer#footer.page-footer`

Comment: `$(data).find('footer').length` is also zero. I actually only added the ID during troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(data)` doesn't return the entire HTML, only the contents of the `<body>` element. As a result, `<nav>` and `<footer>` become top-level elements in `$(data)`, but `find()` only searches descendants.

You should wrap it in another element so you can search it:

```js
let data = `<body>
  <nav>
    <ul id="menuItems">
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>  
  <footer id="footer">stuff</footer>
</body>`;

$("#button").click(function() {
  var contents = $("<div>", {
    html: data
  });
  
  $('#menuItems').replaceWith(contents.find("#menuItems"));
  $('#footer').replaceWith(contents.find("#footer"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="menuItems">
    <li>old item</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<footer id="footer">old stuff</footer>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: That does not seem to be the case: https://i.imgur.com/x8zuQmz.png

Comment: @ScottBeeson That's `data`, not `$(data)`.

Comment: This is part of `$(data)`: https://i.imgur.com/p6ECXRy.png

Comment: My original point is still valid. It only contains the contents of the `<body>` -- `<nav>` and `<footer>` are top-level elements in `$(data)`. Since `.find()` only searches descendants, it doesn't find them.

Comment: This is a more general solution than the other answer, which requires you to use different searching functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter for root level nodes (see [jQuery.find() ignores root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637298/jquery-find-ignores-root-node))

```js
let response = `<body>
  <nav>
    <ul id="menuItems">
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>  
  <footer id="footer">stuff</footer>
</body>`;

console.log('footer : ', $(response).filter('#footer').length);
console.log('menuItems : ', $(response).find('#menuItems').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For a workaround, you can create a custom function like described [in this post](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2011/03/14/a-jquery-find-that-also-finds-the-root-element/).

Comment: Look at the second answer in the link post (function find2)

Comment: Yeah, seems like overkill since this won't need to be extensible.  I appreciate it though.  Is this expected behavior for `find()`?

Comment: @ScottBeeson It's linked to the way Jquery implements a pseudo DOM tree when elements are not in the DOM.

Comment: From doc : Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.